# Python: Django does not get param when use format method for param name

Tags: python, django, string

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.11 for my project and I want iterating to get a list of params with code like this:

```
for idx in range(1, int(number_unit_orders) + 1):
     is_edit = request.POST.get('edit_%s'.format(str(idx)))
     # Do something with is_edit
```

But the `is_edit` is always None although `edit_1` and so on are set in the request object. But the code block below works(use string concatenation):

```
for idx in range(1, int(number_unit_orders) + 1):
     is_edit = request.POST.get('edit_' + str(idx))
     # Do something with is_edit
```

Wonder why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'edit_%s'.format(str(idx))
```

Is mixing up two different types of formatting

You need to  choose one of them and stick to it

```
'edit_%s' % str(idx)  # 'edit_%d % idx
'test_{}'.format(idx)
```

The reason you're getting none is because you're trying to get an object that doesn't exist, it is actually currently looking up the exact string of `edit_%s`

Answer (score 1):

In `format` method you don't use `%` but `{}`.
Please rewrite your line with this method to:

```
is_edit = request.POST.get('edit_{}'.format(idx))
```

Also explicit `str` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Format doesn't work like that. Your code should be:

```
'edit_{0}'.format(str(idx))
```